# Is Posix threads available on embedded Linux platform?

Tags: c++, pthreads

Sometimes I read about (if I'm not interpreting wrong) that posix threads are not available or valid on sone platforms such as some RTOSs which inplements their own threading mechanism.

So, is posix thread can be considered as standard (at least on general purpose OS)? And is it platform independent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"So, is posix thread can be considered as standard (at least on general purpose OS)?"*

No, it's not standard for OS's that POSIX threads are supported.

I'd say that `std::thread` implementations rely on some POSIX thread commonly defined features.

Embedded Linux platforms are POSIX compatible of course, and you can rely on [`pthreads`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html).

Windows platforms (counting as a general purpose OS) for instance, doesn't support POSIX threads natively, but there are wrapper APIs available with e.g. MinGW or cygwin.

> *"that posix threads are not available or valid on sone platforms such as some RTOSs which inplements their own threading mechanism."*

Other embedded platforms like FreeRTOS don't support that threading model directly, but are eligible to write a POSIX wrapper.

The basic thread semantics could be usually wrapped well for the POSIX standard requirements, and injected to newlib or whatever you like to use as binding for realising the standards implementation.

Comment: It is not an answer to the qeustion.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You're falling back to your old revenge downvoting patterns. I'm a bit tired of you.

Comment: Where do you see a revenge? In my opinion this answer does not deserve to be the best. The other answer in this thread is better. I am ready to discuss the question.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow _"here do you see a revenge?"_ It's a pattern in your behaviour, and I've seen that earlier (I even believe, you've been already banned for that earlier this year).

Comment: It is funny to see that you think that you are untouchable. I was ready to discuss the question but it seems you do not want to do this. I am sorry.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Well, let's discuss, how to improve my answer or give your better one yourself.

Comment: I already upvoted another answer. I think you should delete your answer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Indeed I agree the other answer is in more depth as I was giving. I would, but I can,'t delete this answer, that's the infamous thing. You still have that behavioural pattern to downvote stuff, that can't be deleted from my side, even if deletion would be appropriate. That's the thing that irritates me. I've been flagging for mod attention, can't retract (and still stand with that).

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Well, with some simple improvements my answer was achieved better now. Any points you still want to discuss?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87828/discussion-between-vlad-from-moscow-and--).

Comment: My congratulations! It seems my downvoting was  helpfull for you. Let me to down vote another you answer that you could improve it.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Nope, I've been bringing that to a broader chat platform already:  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25284326#25284326

Comment: I simply try to help others as you who down votes correct answers to improve their skills iin C++ and C. .

Comment: @VladfromMoscow  I agree, that the downvote was helpful to force me to improve my answer with a few trivial edits. Which doesn't answer why you're frequently hunt down disclosed down voters appearing with answers from your site, that look inappropriate.  Not by their technical nature, but answering stuff beyond that and give the OP a real incentive of what they want. IMHO closing that way, that's the most shortcut way letting them glance beyond their own noses. You might show your present nuts, and ask this on Meta StackOverflow finally!

Answer (score 3):

POSIX, the standard that specifies pthread, is a standard (Actually, more a group of standards) defining operating system behavior and functions. An OS either implements the standard or it doesn't. The goal of POSIX is platform independence, all the same OS calls on all platforms, but as with all standards, folks bolts stuff onto the edges to get extra functionality that is not portable or leave stuff out when it becomes problematic.

Linux implements POSIX fairly closely (but not even all families of Linux agree on how closely) so your concern will be with compatibility edge cases that I hope will be well documented at this point.

Windows POSIX support is somewhere below weak so you cannot count on it on general purpose OSes.

I recommend a quick search here on SO, Google or giving Wikipedia a look-over for a better description of POSIX.